# Is ∃x.px=>q equal to ∃x.(px=>q)?

Tags: logic, quantifiers, first-order-logic

I wondered if the sentences

> ∃x.px=>q

equal to

> ∃x.(px=>q).

I think they are equal because of the following example:

The instance of the first sentence:

> If there exist a cow, then it is a mammal.

The instance of second sentence:

> there exist a cow, if it is a cow, then it is a mammal.

If they are not equal, what is wrong with my example?

Comment: Is this a programming question? It looks more like math.

Comment: You might want to post this on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: The notation is slightly unfamiliar - different than what I learned in school. However, if your example sentences are faithful to the logic sentences, then they are obviously not equivalent, because the second one includes a definite statement that "there exist a cow", while the first leaves the possibility of a cow existing or not undefined, and only states that any cow that does exist also happens to be a mammal...

Answer (score 0):

No, they aren't equivalent. Just consider using `false` as `q`.